# how to convert 10Hz signal to 1Hz signal?

Tags: r, dataframe

is it possible to convert a 10 Hz signal into a 1 Hz signal and associate the 1 values in the 10 Hz table into a 1 pulse in the 1 Hz table?

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

```
df10 <- data.frame( seq(5, 7 ,0.1),
                c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
names(df10) <- c("t[10Hz]", "sign")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple aggregation task:

```
aggregate(sign ~ floor(`t[10Hz]`), df10, max)
#  floor(`t[10Hz]`) sign
#1                5    0
#2                6    1
#3                7    0
```

If your data is large, replace `aggregate` with a more efficient "group-by-apply" approach from the various packages implementing these. I'm partial to package data.table.

Comment: can I also apply it to a dataframe with several columns? in the sense that, can I apply it to each column?

Comment: Yes, you can. Study `help("aggregate")` and note that my answer uses the formula method. Pay attention to the examples using `cbind` or the dot notation within the formula.